# Reduce Number of HTTP Requests in Modular Directive System

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, xmlhttprequest

I was recently tasks with building a modular framework that would allow our OWS team to write a "Page Creator" that would allow certain people to create and modify pages on the fly.

I have the entire system written and it has been approved.  The only problem I have now is that they want to try and reduce the number of HTTP Requests being made.

Right now each module (written as a directive) is called as so:

```
<my-custom-module data="/path-to/data/service"></my-custom-module>
```

Each module contains three resources; a template, a stylesheet, and a data object (obtained via AJAX).  So each module makes three separate calls to the server.

Since a page may contain many modules, those requests add up quickly, which is a concern from a front-end perspective due to loading times, and from a back-end perspective due to the sheer number of requests hitting the server (the user set for this is rather large).

All data needs to remain separated so that it can be used on any website/project at any time, so I cannot combine the CSS or markup for any of the modules.  I am honestly stumped about how to go about optimizing this.

Currently all directives are combined into one JS file along with the other JS files for the web application. So the current flow is like this:

1. Page Calls Directive
2. Directive Makes Call for Template
3. Directive Makes Call for Data
4. Template Makes Call for Stylesheet via `include-stylesheet`
   directive

Can anybody point me in the right direction here? Or have any suggestions on reducing the number of requests?

Comment: Combine requests where you can. Make good use of caching. Considering most browsers allow between 2 and 8 simultaneous requests it can be a serious bottleneck in perceived performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine requests" exactly?